# How to delete thumbnails of deleted images in android?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I had links for images in hashset. From that, i downloaded pics.
After I create bitmap from that url, I scan file to put it in gallery so that I can see it in gallery.
I use following code.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(obContext, new String[] { f.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);
```

To see only those particular images in my custom gallery I use folllowing code

```
Cursor imagecursor=managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns, 
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[] {"%myDesiredDirectory%"},  
                null);
```

So it is scanning myDesiredDirectory before showing me gallery. And after scanning, gallery has my images.

But now I have 2 problems:

1. While scanning, it is creating thumbnails for newly downloaded images. These thumbnails also visible in gallery.
   So same pic is visible twice. Which is not desired.
2. in next iteration of my app run, i want to show only new set of images. To achieve that i decided to delete images downloaded from first iteration.

I am using following code to delete all  files in that dir

```
if(dirChk==true){
                        File dir = new File(Path);
                        String[] children = dir.list();
                        String[] pathsOfDeletedThumbs=new String[children.length];
                        Log.d(LOGGER, "dir contains "+children.length);
                        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                            String temp = Path+children[i]; 
                            Log.d(LOGGER, "temp is "+temp);


                           new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
                        }
```

but still those automatically created thumbnails are present in gallery.

Can anybody please help me to avoid creating thumbnails, and if its not avoidable, can we delete thumbnails also when we delete original files??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: how did you resolve the problem?